# changing the height of the div where google maps is drawn in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Mpas Api v3 to display a map in a 200px high div:

```
<div id='propertyKaart'></div>
```

With the normal javascript i'm using this div to display the map:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("propertyKaart"),
                    mapOptions);
                    map.setCenter(punt);
                    map.setZoom(14);
})
```

With a click on a button with class `.mapPuller` I want to change the height of the chart to  lets say 600px:

```
var mapState        
$('.mapPuller').click(function(e){
        if(mapState == 'klein'){
            $('#propertyKaart').animate({height: '600px'}, 200);
            mapState = 'groot'

        }else{
            $('#propertyKaart').animate({height: '200px'}, 200);
            mapState = 'klein';

        }
         //---- here
    })
```

Works like a charm, with only one problem. The map (the tiles, so to say) still think the div is 200px high.

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map%22documentation%22)  I found I had to trigger the resize event when changing the container div. So I added the following code in the .mapPuller function on the `//------ here` spot.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

**But this doesn't work......
Am I missing something?**

When I resize my browser window, the event gets triggered and the tiles seem to do their work.....

Comment: try to not use animate and see if it works

Comment: When changing the animate function, just to an ordinary `.css()` change it works...... But that is strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried resizing the map with jquery's `animate` function and had the same problem with you. The map tiles didn't adapt. But triggering the map `resize` event fixed the problem.

So, maybe there's a problem with scoping. Make sure that the `map` variable is accessible inside `mapPuller` function and make sure that there isn't other errors in the console.

Comment: When I `alert(map)` or `alert(google.maps.event)` I'm getting an object dialog box, so they are being sent to the function.

Comment: Then maybe it's a browser-specific problem. I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Everything looks right.